# Split a declartion of an array string into an array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

What would be the best way to split an a string that a declaration of an array into an array of strings using javascript/jquery. An example of a string I am working with:

```
 franchise[location][1][location_name]
```

I would like it to be converted into an array like:

```
['franchise', 'location', '1', 'location_name']
```

BONUS: If I could also get that numeric value to be an integer and not just a string in one fell swoop, that would be terrific.

Comment: For what reason do you need to do this? It sounds very much like an X/Y question, where you're asking about an attempted solution instead of describing the actual problem, when there may be much better, and simpler, solutions

Comment: The first string is actually a name element for a dynamically created input. All the non numeric elements are constantly generated but the number changes on each iteration of the creation of that input. I need to know the "location number" so I can remove validation flags once the user fixes the validation problems.

Comment: So in turn that string must be coming from somewhere, so the `1` value must be retrievable/accessible from there...?

Comment: I am doing my validation on the php side and adding a class to jquery tab element if it finds that elements within that tag have an error. I can remove the individual error messages once the user meets with the validation requirements but the correct tab is harder to target. I have tried to use `$(this).closest('.tab')` but jQuery isn't finding it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.split` with a regex that matches all the none alpha numeric chars.

Something like that:

```js
const str = 'franchise[location][1][location_name]';
const result = str.split(/\W+/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to just match word characters:

```js
console.log(
  'franchise[location][1][location_name]'.match(/\w+/g)
);
```

To transform the "1" to a number, you might `.map` afterwards:

```js
const initArr = 'franchise[location][1][location_name]'.match(/\w+/g);
console.log(initArr.map(item => !isNaN(item) ? Number(item) : item));
```

Comment: you don't need the `g` in your regex. It will make the match slower if you keep it in.

Comment: You do indeed need `/g` - otherwise, you get `[
  "franchise"
]` only

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 const str = 'franchise[location][1][location_name]';
 const res = str.split(/\W+/).map(i => { return Number(i) ? Number(i) : i;})
```